# How to monitor console logs for application installed with install4j?

Tags: install4j

I need the possibility to monitor Java application console logs.
For Linux it works ok, when I run the executable in the console I get the full stdout log.
But for Windows it doesn't work, even when I start the app from the cmd.

Answer (score 0):

For generated launchers of type "GUI application", you can start the application from the terminal with the argument

```
-console
```

That will not block on the console like for a launcher of type "Console application", but the GUI application will then attach to the invoking console and redirect stdout and stderr there.